# Call App Script function from Angular/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-apps-script

I am new to Google docs app script.

Actually I am looking for insert the text in document from third party application by calling AppScript function by APIs but the getCursor function is getting null so i am not ableto get cursor location. Below is my script:

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor().insertText("Test...")
```

Response:

```
{ "done": true, "error": { "message": "ScriptError", "code": 3, "details": [ { "errorType": "ScriptError", "errorMessage": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertText' of null", "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionError", "scriptStackTraceElements": [ { "function": "myFuction", "lineNumber": 31 } ] } ] } }
```

Is there any way to do that? Is there any JS library to call Appscript function?

Thanks - Sahi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Situation:

If I understand your situation correctly:

- You have [deployed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments) a script that is [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to a Google Docs.
- You are calling this deployment using a 3rd party.

#### Issue:

The problem here is that you cannot get information on a user's cursor (and hence cannot use [getCursor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getcursor)) in this context. That's because there's no client associated with this script execution. Even if the user has the document opened on a browser window, the script execution doesn't "know" about this, both circumstances are unrelated to each other.

Think for example about the possibility of opening the document on a second tab, and putting the cursor in a different place than the first one. Which location should `getCursor` point to? None of them, because the script is not getting called from there.

Now, if you called your function from that opened tab, then you could get the cursor information. For example, you could have a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms) call it. Or maybe you could be using this [as an add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/docs). Or you could just click `Extensions > Apps Script` and call the function directly from your script editor.

When calling this from a third party, even if the request is authenticated with the same user who has a browser tab with the document opened, there's no way you can get that tab's cursor information. The script can get the [active document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getactivedocument) because it is bound to it, but no other data that is specifically related to the opened tab (so something like [getSelection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getselection) would also be inaccessible).

#### Workarounds:

So, if you want to add text to the document, you have to use methods that don't use data specifically related to an open tab. For example, you could use [Body.appendParagraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendparagraphtext) to append text to the end of your document, or use [findText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern) to first find a certain word in your document and append your text there. That is, you have to use methods that relate to the document as it is, not to the document being opened in your browser.

Another option would be not calling this using a 3rd party, and use this instead as an add-on, or what have you. But that depends on the specific circumstances and requirements of your project.

Comment: I used as add-on also but while I am calling add-on function by API, still it is not working

Comment: @SahiRepswal I'm not sure what you mean by `I am calling add-on function by API`, but if you are calling this from a context unrelated to the tab opened in your browser, this cannot work, as explained in my answer.